# Object is not an instance of declaring class while deploying EAR application

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ear, illegalargumentexception

I have such a structure of my project
EmployeeManager (ear)
 
  |--EmployeeManagerEJB (jar)
  |--EmployeeManagerJSF (war)
  |--EmployeeManagerIntegration (jar)

EmployeeManager  - .ear project containing X_EJB, X_JSF, X_Integration
EmployeeManagerEJB - EJB Project packed into jar containing JPA Entities, EJB Stateless Bean Implementations 
EmployeeManagerJSF  - Dynamic web project containing JSF's xhtml pages and controllers
EmployeeManagerIntegration - Interfaces implemented by EJBs (used in JSF project), DTOs

I am using CDI in EJB Bean Implementations to e.g. inject one EJB into another (i'm referencing by interface, not by implementation class). I am also using these Stateless Beans via CDI in X_JSF's controller classes. When I'm trying to deploy an EAR I receive stack trace:

```
16:52:13,694 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EmployeeManager.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EmployeeManager.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.resolution.QualifierInstance.createValues(QualifierInstance.java:128)
at org.jboss.weld.resolution.QualifierInstance.of(QualifierInstance.java:95)
at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifier(ResolvableBuilder.java:147)
at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifiers(ResolvableBuilder.java:197)
at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifiers(ResolvableBuilder.java:192)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolveDecorators(BeanManagerImpl.java:885)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanInjectionTarget.java:109)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetInitializationContext.initialize(InjectionTargetInitializationContext.java:42)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.initialize(InjectionTargetService.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:434)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
... 3 more
```

**This is the only error-type message I get from wildfly, don't know what may be wrong here and where to begin searching.** 
I suspect that CDI error is the reason somehow, but dont know how to debug or something. Any suggestions ?

Sample code with injections:
1. Interface

```
@Local
public interface ChartService extends Serializable {
    Collection<String> getSomething();
}
```

2. Implementation

```
@Stateless
public class ChartServiceImpl implements ChartService {
    @Inject DateService dateService;
}
```

Comment: post code where there are injections

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: And where are you injecting your EJBs? Do you mind providing that code also?

Comment: I've just figured it out. One day I used some tutorial describing creation own Qualifier annotations which parameters were Class<T> types. As long as my project was in single .war, everything worked fine, but finally that was the cause.
Anyway, thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1., Use Qualifiers to identify the injectable implementation

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html

or

2., Use @Alternative and declare one of the alternatives in the beans.xml

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html